# how to centerlized Client Machine Event Log Auditing to one server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-event-log

We have Windows Server 2003 Enterprise DC for 2000 Windows XP SP3 Client Machine. We **just** want to centralized audit account logon/logoff event, security event log in windows client on one server. 
we are looking for best solution for this purpose, specially microsoft solution?

Is there any solution for SCCCM 2007?HOW?

because we have 2000 client machine, the database of log files is too large, and we just want to gather logon/logoff event.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it via WMI with some scripting to pull remote logs matching a specific eventID, though it can be slow.